# validate information before entering an ionic view globally

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have seen that the official documentation of IONIC offers these methods to validate the access or exit of a view.

[image]

but this is done in each view, I would like to know if there is a method or way of doing this globally so as not to do it view by sight. for example, I would like to validate globally without injecting anything into any component that if there is a token in localstorage redirects me to the first screen, otherwise it will allow me to continue in the current view.

How can I do it? I'm new to this so please try to be a little understanding if it's not too much trouble.

in angular.js he did it in the following way:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, trans => {});
```

Comment: which version of ionic are you working with?

Comment: @SurajRao I am using the version 3

Comment: ionViewCanEnter is generally used for this.. But that is in each page

Comment: @SurajRao yes.... :(

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add route guards.

You will just add a `canActivate` property on routes you want to guard.

Take a look at this example service:

```js
// src/app/auth/auth-guard.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

The service injects `AuthService` and `Router` and has a single method called `canActivate`. This method is necessary to properly implement the `CanActivate` interface.

The `canActivate` method returns a boolean indicating whether or not navigation to a route should be allowed. If the user isn’t authenticated, they are re-routed to some other place, in this case a route called `/login`.

And in the file where you have your routes:

```js
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { 
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard] 
  }
];
```

As you can see, the profile page has `canActivate` property. You will just add it to routes that you want to secure.

Full implementation is here https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: Ionic uses its own navigation stack. Refer [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/). Not the angular router directly. Have you tried auth guard in Ionic?